# Downloading a form-generated file programmatically

Tags: c#, httprequest

I am trying to programmatically download a file that is generated from user input (HTML form) on a web site. The web site requires the user to log in.

I have studied how the site works using the Tamper Data Firefox plug-in, and that's basically what's going on when doing the download manually in Firefox :

- I go to the site's home page
- I enter my credentials and click "Log in"
- This triggers a POST request to URL A and sets an "IdSes" (Session ID I guess) cookie (among others)
- I go to the page that let me download the file
- I input some stuff (file format etc.)
- I click "Download"
- This triggers a POST request to URL B (an ASP page). The response has code 200 and contains the file.

By tampering the POST request to URL B, I have made sure that the IdSes cookie is the only one required for the request to succeed. If the IdSes value is not correct or absent, the response has code 302 and I'm redirected to URL A, and I appear to be still logged in (my name is displayed). If I put junk in the POST data (which originally comes from the form), I get to the right ASP page, but it displays an error.

Now I try to do the downloading with C#, without doing what I think is unnecessary (ie. all the GETs):

```
// URL A is loginUrl, URL B is retrieveUrl

public void RetrieveFile(
        string loginUrl, IDictionary<string, string> loginData, 
        string retrieveUrl, IDictionary<string, string> retrieveData) {
    var cookies = new CookieContainer();
    var loginRequest = CreatePostRequest(loginUrl, loginData);
    loginRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
    var loginResponse = loginRequest.GetResponse();
    loginResponse.Close();
    var retrieveRequest = CreatePostRequest(retrieveUrl, retrieveData);
    retrieveRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
    var response = retrieveRequest.GetResponse();
    using (
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream(),
            outputFile = new FileStream("response.html", FileMode.Create)) {
        responseStream.CopyTo(outputFile);
    }
}

private HttpWebRequest CreatePostRequest(string url, IDictionary<string, string> data) {
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    var postData = EncodePostData(data);
    request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
    return request;
}

private byte[] EncodePostData(IDictionary<string, string> data) {
    var dataAsStrings =
        from entry in data
        select String.Format("{0}={1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
    var dataAsString = String.Join("&", dataAsStrings);
    // Encode in Latin-1 / ISO 8859-1
    var dataAsBytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(dataAsString);
    return dataAsBytes;
}
```

What happens is that "response.html" contains the page located at URL A, just as if the IdSes cookie had the wrong value or were absent. However if I print all the cookies that are present in `cookies` after `loginRequest.GetResponse()`, IdSes is present. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Probably not correct but why don't you try closing the response after the first call to `GetResponse`? I've seen unruly stuff happen if I didn't do that, for some reason it might be related. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Oh, I did not known I had to close it if I didn't use its stream. It didn't solve the issue however. I'll edit my code to reflect the change. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Because it is a POST request, I'm wondering whether the website validates the REFERER header, and if not on the same domain (or empty!), basically doesn't treat your request as valid, resulting in the behaviour you are seeing. Now if only it was a GET request, you'd be golden.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is a POST request, I'm wondering whether the website validates the `HTTP_REFERER` header, and if not on the same domain (or empty!), basically doesn't treat your request as valid, resulting in the behaviour you are seeing.

What you could try is to spoof the HTTP_REFERER header on your retrieve request and see what happens.

`retrieveRequest.Referer = "http://www.originatingdomain.com";`

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's been so long though that I don't have the code anymore, or even an account on that particular website. Also this website has probably been completely redone since. So I can't test your suggestion. Thank you still. :)

Comment: No worries, I only noticed the age of the question after responding. It came up quite high on the list of Unanswered! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like you are passing the cookies you initially retrieved from loginRequest to the retrieveRequest handler.

change

```
retrieveRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
```

to

```
retrieveRequest.CookieContainer = loginRequest.CookieContainer;
```

and see what happens.

Comment: CookieContainer is a class so only the reference is passed around. It's all the same object. I tried it anyway just to be sure, and it doesn't change the result.